# C++: Passing Operator as Parameter leads to Error "expected an identifier"

Tags: c++, tensorflow, visual-studio-2015, compilation, parameter-passing

I compiled Tensorflow for C++ by using bazel 0.20.0 and VS2015

I created a simple C++-Project in VS2019 and tried to build it
but following problem occurs:

The code part in ...\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h ,that is affected:

```
// Helper functions for CHECK_OP macro.
// The (int, int) specialization works around the issue that the compiler
// will not instantiate the template version of the function on values of
// unnamed enum type - see comment below.
// The (size_t, int) and (int, size_t) specialization are to handle unsigned
// comparison errors while still being thorough with the comparison.
#define TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(name, op)                                 \
  template <typename T1, typename T2>                                     \
  inline string* name##Impl(const T1& v1, const T2& v2,                   \
                            const char* exprtext) {                       \
    if (TF_PREDICT_TRUE(v1 op v2))                                        \
      return NULL;                                                        \
    else                                                                  \
      return ::tensorflow::internal::MakeCheckOpString(v1, v2, exprtext); \
  }                                                                       \
  inline string* name##Impl(int v1, int v2, const char* exprtext) {       \
    return name##Impl<int, int>(v1, v2, exprtext);                        \
  }                                                                       \
  inline string* name##Impl(const size_t v1, const int v2,                \
                            const char* exprtext) {                       \
    if (TF_PREDICT_FALSE(v2 < 0)) {                                       \
      return ::tensorflow::internal::MakeCheckOpString(v1, v2, exprtext); \
    }                                                                     \
    const size_t uval = (size_t)((unsigned)v1);                           \
    return name##Impl<size_t, size_t>(uval, v2, exprtext);                \
  }                                                                       \
  inline string* name##Impl(const int v1, const size_t v2,                \
                            const char* exprtext) {                       \
    if (TF_PREDICT_FALSE(v2 >= std::numeric_limits<int>::max())) {        \
      return ::tensorflow::internal::MakeCheckOpString(v1, v2, exprtext); \
    }                                                                     \
    const size_t uval = (size_t)((unsigned)v2);                           \
    return name##Impl<size_t, size_t>(v1, uval, exprtext);                \
  }

// We use the full name Check_EQ, Check_NE, etc. in case the file including
// base/logging.h provides its own #defines for the simpler names EQ, NE, etc.
// This happens if, for example, those are used as token names in a
// yacc grammar.
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_EQ, ==)  // Compilation error with CHECK_EQ(NULL, x)?
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_NE, !=)  // Use CHECK(x == NULL) instead.
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LE, <=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LT, <)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GE, >=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GT, >)
#undef TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL
```

leads to following errors:
"**expected an identifier**" at the lines

```
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_EQ, ==)  // Compilation error with CHECK_EQ(NULL, x)?
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_NE, !=)  // Use CHECK(x == NULL) instead.
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LE, <=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LT, <)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GE, >=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GT, >)
```

I don't see the problem.
I am a Visual Studio and C++-Noob but those lines should be valid.

I tried the solution in:
[Passing operator as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530588/passing-operator-as-a-parameter)

where `#define TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(name, op)` is replaced with `#define TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(name, std::function<bool(bool,bool)> op)`

but that didn't work and I don't think that I want it to be a template.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to [update](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) bazel version, cause MS2015 may be compatible with bazel 0.20, but MS2019 is not.

[Checkout compatibility table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu)

Comment: I'll try that in the next few days and tell the result